# searching for a filename with extension and printing its relative path

Tags: python, dir, os.walk

I have the below code to print the filename which is find criteria with file extension  *.org. How could I print the relative path of the file found.  Thanks in advance

```
def get_filelist() : 

directory = "\\\\networkpath\\123\\abc\\"
filelist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('Org'):
            print(str(dirs) +"\\" + str(file)) #prints empty list [] followed by filename
            filelist.append(os.path.splitext(file)[0])

return (filelist)
```

Please see me as novice in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`files` and `dirs` list the children of `root`. `dirs` thus lists siblings of `file`. You want to print this instead:

```
print(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file)))
```

Comment: Thank you..  but can you tell me how to get the relative path of the file

Comment: You could use `os.path.relpath` to find the relative path from the current working directory. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.walk#os.path.relpath

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `os.path.join`:

```
def get_filelist() : 

    directory = "\\\\networkpath\\123\\abc\\"
    filelist = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('org'): # here 'org' will be in small letter
                print(os.path.join(root,file))
                filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file))

    return filelist
```

Comment: Dirs is a list, not a directory

Comment: type mistake, it should be root in here

Comment: @Hackaholic : any suggestions for relative path of the file ?